# I keep getting the error "Assets\ThirdPersonMovement.cs(49,30): error CS0117: 'Input' does not contain a definition for 'getAxis'"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ThirdPersonMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public CharacterController controller;
    public float speed = 6f;
    public float turnSmoothTime = 0.1f;
    public Transform cam;
    private float verticalVelocity;
    private float gravity = 14.0f;
    private float jumpForce = 10.0f;
    float turnSmoothVelocity;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical).normalized;

        if (direction.magnitude >= 0.1f)
        {
            float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.x, direction.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + cam.eulerAngles.y;
            float angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle, ref turnSmoothVelocity, turnSmoothTime);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, angle, 0f);
            Vector3 moveDir = Quaternion.Euler(0f, targetAngle, 0f) * Vector3.forward;
            controller.Move(moveDir.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (controller.isGrounded)
        {
            verticalVelocity = -gravity * Time.deltaTime;
            if (Input.getKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                verticalVelocity = jumpForce;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            verticalVelocity -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        Vector3 moveVector = Vector3.zero;
        moveVector.x = Input.getAxis("Horizontal") * speed;
        moveVector.y = verticalVelocity;
        moveVector.z = Input.getAxis("Vertical") * speed;
        controller.Move(moveVector * Time.deltaTime);

    }
}
```

It has been giving me this error for a couple weeks and I can't figure it out.

I've tried seeing if anybody else has had any issues and looking back at how others have overcome this issue, but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Where is `Input` defined and what is it?

Comment: I figured it out, nvm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# is case-sensitive.

```
        moveVector.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed;
        moveVector.y = verticalVelocity;
        moveVector.z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;
```